# jquery is missing when using hubspot forms inside wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I would like to integrate hubspot forms within my wordpress site, it all works fine I can submit the form and see the data from hubspot but there is only one problem with the callback function **onFormReady()** is not being executed due the jQuery is not present.

The error is:
The onFormReady function in hbspt.forms.create requires jQuery. It was not run.

Eventhout I have enqued jquery from function.php and I can actually use jQuery for example withi the head script section works.

This is the hubspot code:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"></script>
<script>
hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "x",
    formId: "xxxx",
    onFormReady: function() {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
</script>
```

Any idea how would I be able to execute some code within onFormReady()?

Also if this is not possible, can we somehow catch any submission that happening on the site using jQuery? I tried few ways I was not able to catch the form submission using jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

I had to add this script 
`<script charset="utf-8" src="http://js.hubspot.com/forms/current.js"></script>` 
to make it work.